# Learning C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone recommend any good resources for learning C++ Templates?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) to be helpful on numerous occasions.  Looks like they've got a pretty good intro to [templates.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates.html)

If its an actual book you're looking for, [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) is a classic with a great section on templates.

Answer (score 12):

I recomned that you get [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) it's an excellent resource and reference.

Answer (score 5):

This is a more advanced, but very useful, book on templates and template use.

[Modern C++ Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

Comment: To understand this book you'll need to understand how templates work first. It's an interesting book but not for the faint of heart, nor for beginners - which the OP is I think, if he needs to ask this question.

Comment: Only a beginner to Templates, not C++.

Comment: As long as the basics are there, you can learn most of the important aspects about templates from their use in this book. Agreed that it is a huge learning curve to do it this way though :)

Comment: Yeah beginner of templates I meant. For a beginner of C++ this book is definitely way out of league.

Answer (score 4):

Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) is how I learned about templates. The first volume has an introductory chapter and the second volume has an in-depth chapter on templates.

There's Bjarne Stroustrop's [The C++ Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201889544) which has a good chapter on them. And [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260) which is about the standard library, but would definitely help you get a better understanding of how templates could be used in the real world. .

Comment: Eckel's done me a few favors with his books - all for free!

Comment: +1, Eckel books was brilliant for me

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to differentiate between generic programming and template metaprogramming (which is more like another paradigm)

Generic programming can be learnt from the [C++ bible](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html), but you can just as well take a look at the java generics etc...

one about metaprogramming: Josuttis' book [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/)

Answer (score 2):

The 2 volumes of 'Thinking in C++' go over the basics of templates. They can either be bought in print, or downloaded for free (and legal) use [here](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html).

Answer (score 0):

"The C++ Programming language" by Bjarne Stroustrop