# is "const arguments and non-cost return statement " possible?

Tags: c++, constants

Is the below function definition is legal or not?

```
T& GetMax(const T& t1, const T& t2)
{
    if (t1 > t2)
    {
        return t2;
    }
    // else 
    return t2;
}
```

It is written that :
"At the return statements, compiler would complain that t1 or t2 cannot be converted to non-const."
I read it in this site :  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1

Does it mean that it is illegal ,if not what else? Could you provide example of use of it?
Could you provide some clear explanation to me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you mean that you want to return t1 or t2? Have you tried to implement it and compile it? What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: *Is the below function definition is legal or not?* It depends on what you're doing within the function. *It is written that ...* It is written *where*? Some context would be nice.

Comment: "*Is the below function definition is legal or not?*" No, it has too many dots in it. Seriously, if the compiler complains about the return statement, **show us the return statement**. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more guidelines.

Comment: I also think that it is legal . But I read it in the url which i said . The author of the article doesn't mention about the function of the body . He doesn't say whether the function returns t1 or t2 or another thing . He only says that "At the return statements, compiler would complain that t1 or t2 cannot be converted to non-const."  Thus i am confused.

Comment: @user1308990 Have you actually READ the article? I Quote: *"You should have noticed, I have not added const to any of two parameters passed. This is required; since function returns non-const reference of type T"*

Comment: @user1308990: You copied the prototype, but just a few paragraphs up is the body of that function, including the return statements.  I copied it into the question for you.

Comment: In scanning that article, I'm not a fan. I wonder if there are better resources to learn template programming.

Comment: Oh , Mr. Duck Thank you really. The author don't say about body. Because he mentions about the function above. Good point. I don't do the same mistake again. Moreover , not book but glasses is right suggestion,mihai :D

Comment: @user1308990 Patience usually helps. Try to get comfortable with the C++ syntax first, and then dive into templates. I'm not sure if that article is the place to start, though. You can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152318/learning-c-templates) some good alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should it be illegal? Your function can use some global state to return, while it is forbidden to return its arguments.

```
int& foo(const int& a, const int& b)
{
    static int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

**ADDED**

You cannot return one of your argument, because it will violate `const` constrains. You can

- return from function by value
- use non-const argument types

if returning non-const in your case would be possible, one could write

```
foo(5, 4) = 3;
```

which has no sense.

You can not also return reference to some temporary automatic variable, created inside function, as it will be destroyed, when function finished.

Comment: Added the body of the function to the question

Comment: This is a good idea how to introduce a bug into your code. I don't think that the function works as intended, though legal. Call it two times with different arguments and assign results to two different variables. I don't get why this is up-voted and the answer suggesting avoiding such constructions got down-voted.

Comment: @luk32, it is just illustration of possibility. The minimal example.  All `operator=` member functions accept constant references and return non-constant references, for example. While downvoted question suggest one return refrence to local, which is _actually_ bas advice.

Comment: @lol well i see the question changed a bit. Still, as I stated, it is legal. OK. But coming up with good example is not easy. In my opinion yours suggest you can write a function instantiate a variable in it and return as a reference. `int x=foo(1,2); int y=foo(2,3);` won't produce x=2 and y=5. And I was not talking about down-voted question I was talking about answer by @Lukos which I find perfecly fine. Returning reference to a local variable is always a bad idea. `static` does not help that much. In fact `int c = a + b;` would also compile.
`

Comment: @luk32, _Lukos_ states: '_If you must use your format, you would have to create a local clone of one of the inputs and return that instead_'. Isn't it returning reference to a local variable? Also second advise of using pointer not seem to be good also.

Comment: I think he means `T& GetMax(const T& t1){ T* ret = new T(t1); return *ret;}` And it seems like the only way to get a persistent reference back. It is also bad, because the caller would need to explicitly call delete on the object. How would he know that? The problem is, the question tries to achieve something generally bizzare =)

Answer (score 3):

The definition is fine.  The function can return a reference to some other variable than `t1` or `t2`.  The compiler would only complain if you tried to return `t1` or `t2`.

Comment: Added the body of the function to the question

Answer (score 1):

It is **illegal** and the **compiler would give an error message**.

The reason is the function returns a `const` which is in contrast to its definition for the return value; i.e. because the return value has not been defined as `const`. However, it is not the signature that is problematic; the problem is in return statements and this is why the compiler gives error at return statements.

if you change it in this way:

```
const T& GetMax(const T& t1, const T& t2)
{
    if (t1 > t2)
    {
        return t2;
    }
    // else 
    return t2;
}
```

the code will be compiled with no errors. However, if outside of this function somewhere else you do:

```
GetMax(x,y) = 0;
```

the compiler would fail at this line because you are assigning value to a const (= the return value of the function).

Answer (score -1):

It is legal but not recommended to return references since the reference would usually be to a local variable. You would normally return a pointer to an object you have 'new'd but then the caller would have to delete that item. If you must use your format, you would have to create a local clone of one of the inputs and return that instead.